# Selenium doesn`t create a session.

Tags: python, selenium

I am a beginner in Python. I try to make a parser. But something is wrong with chromdriver, i think so. I need some help. Run the code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv, sys, os, urllib.request, requests, datetime, time
##import pandas as pd
##from pandas import read_csv

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

pang_list = [ 'http://www.amcal.com.au/brands/our-john-frieda-range',
              'http://www.amcal.com.au/brands/our-oral-b-range',
              'http://www.amcal.com.au/brands/our-tommee-tippee-range',]              


def driv():
    chromedriver = "chromedriver"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def get_links(soup):
    box = []
    block = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'product_info'})
    for aa in block:
        obj = aa.find('a').get('href')
        box.append(obj)
    df = pd.DataFrame(box, columns=['Link'])
    if os.path.exists('links.csv'): head = False
    else:  head = True 
    df.to_csv('links.csv',sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='a', header=head)

def max_rows(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageSizeTop"]/tbody/tr/td[2]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dijit_MenuItem_2_text"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    return soup

driver = driv()
for ii in pang_list[:]:
    print(ii)
    driver.get(ii)
    soup = max_rows(driver)
    get_links(soup)

    nn = 1
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="WC_SearchBasedNavigationResults_pagination_link_right_categoryResults_Top"]').click()
            time.sleep(5)
            soup_ = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
            get_links(soup_)
            print(nn)
            nn += 1
        except: break
```

The terminal gives out an error:

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception from tab crashed

my system:

Chrome ver. 67
chromedriver ver.2.39
selenium ver.3
python 3.7
win 32

I tried to run as administrator. But it did not work.
I will be happy to help.